# syntax error, unexpected T_AS, expecting ')'

Tags: php

```
<?php
include('database.class.php');
$sql = new Database(NULL);

$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
$dump = array();
foreach ($ids as $index as $id)
        $dump[] = $id['UserId'].' | REGLINK - http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$id['UserId'].'&k2='.$id['k2'].'&mode=1';
$DumpFile = 'ids.txt';

if(file_exists($DumpFile)) {
        unlink($DumpFile);
}
file_put_contents($DumpFile, implode("\r\n", $dump));
die(count($dump).' ids were dumped into the list.'."\n");
?>
```

I've checked and retried many things, i just don't get what is wrong.

Comment: Where is your question ?

Answer (score 13):

```
foreach ($ids as $index as $id)
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($ids as $index => $id)
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() is what i'm getting now.

Comment: If you `var_dump($ids)` chances are it's a boolean false and not an array. It looks like your sql is malformed. It should look something like `SELECT id FROM table`.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
foreach ($ids as $index as $id)
```

It's not proper syntax and you're not using `$index` anywhere. Just use this:

```
foreach ($ids as $id)
```

See the [Manual page about foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

You **`foreach`** is wrong. Try like this. **Key - Value** pair are used to denote by this operator **`=>`**

```
<?php
include('database.class.php');
$sql = new Database(NULL);

$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
$dump = array();
foreach ($ids as $index=>$id)
        $dump[] = $id['UserId'].' | REGLINK - http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$id['UserId'].'&k2='.$id['k2'].'&mode=1';
$DumpFile = 'ids.txt';

if(file_exists($DumpFile)) {
    unlink($DumpFile);
}
file_put_contents($DumpFile, implode("\r\n", $dump));
die(count($dump).' ids were dumped into the list.'."\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct code

```
<?php
include('database.class.php');
$sql = new Database(NULL);

$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);
$dump = array();
foreach ($ids as $index => $id)
        $dump[] = $id['UserId'].' | REGLINK - http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$id['UserId'].'&k2='.$id['k2'].'&mode=1';
$DumpFile = 'ids.txt';

if(file_exists($DumpFile)) {
        unlink($DumpFile);
}
file_put_contents($DumpFile, implode("\r\n", $dump));
die(count($dump).' ids were dumped into the list.'."\n");
?>
```